# WordPress.org, by clicking a button, change post->comment_status = "open" to "closed" from the front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how by clicking a button, on a WordPress.org site, I can change one posts comment status from "open" to "closed". I know I can do this on the back end (as the admin), but I need it to work on the front end (for a specific user role). I tried using 'wp_update_post( $my_args )' in combine with 'add_action('save_post', 'my_function')', but no luck so far. Appreciate any help.
The function I was trying to work with, from WordPress Codex, is here.

```
function my_function( ){

    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( 251 ) ){

        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action('save_post', 'my_function');

        // update the post, which calls save_post again
        $my_args = array(
            'ID'           => 251,
            'comment_status'   => 'closed'
        );
        wp_update_post( $my_args );

        // re-hook this function
        add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug more into WordPress Codex and found this piece of code (the code is being adapted a little to my needs).

```
//Change post comment status from "open" to "closed"
global $wpdb;

if ( ! $post = get_post( 251 ) ) return;

if ( 'closed' == $post->comment_status ) return;
    
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'comment_status' => 'closed' ), array( 'ID' => $post->ID ) );

clean_post_cache( $post->ID );
    
$old_status = $post->comment_status;

$post->comment_status = 'closed';

wp_transition_post_status( 'closed', $old_status, $post );
```